# PostgreSQL answers "pg_toast does not exist" for query without pg_toast in it

Tags: postgresql

Here is an [interactive db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9ba1cedb90300de0652dec4b324752c2) demonstrating the problem:

When executing the query

```
SELECT
  n.nspname :: REGCLASS :: TEXT AS schema_name,
  conrelid :: REGCLASS :: TEXT  AS table_name,
  conname :: REGCLASS :: TEXT   AS fk_name
FROM pg_constraint c
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.connamespace
WHERE contype = 'f'
      AND n.nspname :: REGCLASS :: TEXT = 'public'
      AND conrelid :: REGCLASS :: TEXT = ANY ('{film, film_actor}')
ORDER BY conrelid :: REGCLASS :: TEXT, contype DESC;
```

PostgreSQL answers with what seems like a totally unrelated statement:

```
ERROR:  relation "pg_toast" does not exist
```

**Nowhere did I mention `pg_toast`**, so why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `:: REGCLASS` operator. By using it, you are asserting that whatever it is used upon is the name of a relation.

`pg_toast` is a schema, not a relation.
Therefore, evaluating the expression

```
 n.nspname :: REGCLASS :: TEXT = 'public'
```

triggers the error.

The query should instead only cast `conrelid`:

```
SELECT
  c.connamespace :: REGNAMESPACE :: TEXT AS schema_name,
  conrelid :: REGCLASS :: TEXT           AS table_name,
  conname                                AS fk_name
FROM pg_constraint c
WHERE contype = 'f'
      AND c.connamespace :: REGNAMESPACE :: TEXT = 'public'
      AND conrelid :: REGCLASS :: TEXT = ANY ('{film, film_actor}')
ORDER BY conrelid :: REGCLASS :: TEXT;
```

Comment: You can use `connamespace::REGNAMESPACE` and avoid the `pg_namespace` join altogether

Comment: @NickBarnes: Thanks, didn't know that!

Answer (score -2):

When the contents of a varchar, text, or bytea column exceed a certain size (2Ko), this content is saved in a TOAST table

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.